# while trying to find total number of subset of a set using recursion, I am getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, recursion, set

//recursion program to find all the subset of a set

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const int n =3;
int arr[n]={1,2,3};

void pass(int *tmp,int tmpArrayIndex, int OriginalArrayIndex)    
/*
*   int* tmp is temporary array to store 
*   int tmpArrayIndex == size of array is diiferent at different level, indicates the position to insert element
*   int OriginalArrayIndex == positon of element in original array for which decision is to made ot select or reject a element
*/
{
    if(OriginalArrayIndex == n)
    {
        cout<<tmp<<endl;
        return;
    }
    tmp[tmpArrayIndex] = arr[OriginalArrayIndex];
    pass(tmp,tmpArrayIndex+1,OriginalArrayIndex+1);
    pass(tmp,tmpArrayIndex,OriginalArrayIndex+1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *tmp;
    pass(tmp,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

the program compiles successfully, but while executing it shows segmentation fault.
the expected output of the above program should be
123
12
13
1
23
2
empty
total 8 subset as 2^3=8.

Comment: `tmp` is not initialized. You should lern how to use a debugger.

Comment: Local uninitialized variables are really uninitialized, and will have an *indeterminate* value. Using this value in any way (like dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which is what you're doing with e.g. `tmp[tmpArrayIndex]`) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude after making the correction, from `int *tmp;` to  `int* tmp = new int[n];` and adding `int tmpArrayIndex = 0;` `int OriginalArrayIndex = 0;` to main method , which eliminates the error of **segmentation fault**, but still I am not getting the required answer. output after correcting 
`0x7fffe83dee70`
`0x7fffe83dee70`
`0x7fffe83dee70`
`0x7fffe83dee70`
`0x7fffe83dee70`
`0x7fffe83dee70`
`0x7fffe83dee70`
`0x7fffe83dee70`

Comment: What output did you expect? You're printing the *pointer* `tmp`, you're not printing the data being pointed to. Please edit your question to improve it, after reading about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Why do you need a separate array at all? You have already defined a global one, so you could just have `pass(arr, 0, 0);` (note that arrays decay to pointers automatically in contexts where a pointer is required).

Comment: @Aconcagua arr is a reference array `arr={1,2,3}`, elements of `tmp` array `tmp[i]` points to the element of `arr` array. For instance element of `tmp` array pointing to the first element of `arr` i.e pointing to {1}, so it can either accept it or reject it, to add into its `tmp` array.If it accept it to its array, then the resulting `tmp` array by now should be {1}.

Comment: If you want the *elements* of `tmp` *point* to elements of `arr`, then these elements need to be pointers themselves, thus `tmp` would need to be either an array of pointers (`int* tmp[n]`) or a pointer to such one (`int** tmp`).

Answer (score 0):

There's no references or pointers for the "array" `tmp`. The variable `tmp` is a pointer true, but if you do `tmp = new int[3]` then `tmp` will point to the first element of a *new* array that have no relation to `arr`. And `tmp[i] = arr[i]` ***copies the elements***, the two arrays are still distinct and separate, and nothing in the array pointed to by `tmp` will "reference" or "point" to any element of `arr`.

Somewhat graphically the two arrays and the pointer will look something like this (after `tmp = new int[3]`):

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| arr[0] | arr[1] | arr[2] |
+--------+--------+--------+

+-----+     +--------+--------+--------+
| tmp | --> | tmp[0] | tmp[1] | tmp[2] |
+-----+     +--------+--------+--------+
```

The two arrays are two separate and distinct entities without relationship.

---

And as mentioned

```
tmp[i] = arr[i];
```

copies the values from `arr[i]` to `tmp[i]`. It's similar to doing

```
int temporary_value_copy = arr[i];
tmp[i] = temporary_value_copy;
```

With the two lines above, would you still claim that `tmp[i]` "references" or "points" to `arr[i]`? I hope not.

---

Furthermore (and as mentioned), since `tmp` is a pointer then

```
std::cout << tmp;
```

will print the pointer itself, not the possible data it might point to. To print all elements of the array that `tmp` is pointing to then you need a loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    std::cout << tmp[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code after **suggestion** from **Some programmer dude**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int n =3;
int arr[n]={1,2,3};

void pass(int *tmp,int tmpArrayIndex, int OriginalArrayIndex)
{
    if(OriginalArrayIndex == n)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<tmpArrayIndex;++j)
            cout<<tmp[j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
    tmp[tmpArrayIndex] = arr[OriginalArrayIndex];
    pass(tmp,tmpArrayIndex+1,OriginalArrayIndex+1);
    pass(tmp,tmpArrayIndex,OriginalArrayIndex+1);
}
int main(void)
{
    int* tmp = new int[n];
    int tmpArrayIndex = 0;
    int OriginalArrayIndex = 0;
    pass(tmp, tmpArrayIndex,OriginalArrayIndex);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 
1 2 
1 3 
1 
2 3 
2 
3
```

which is the expected output.

```
PS: a newline after last output entry i.e 3, indicates empty subset.
```